# Read XML File with variable tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have created an XML file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employee_Info>
<Employee>
<Name> Blah </Name>
<ID> 001 </ID>
<Dept> ISDC </Dept>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name> Bleh </Name>
<ID> 002 </ID>
<Dept> COE </Dept>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name> Bah </Name>
<ID> 003 </ID>
<Dept> Roll_Out </Dept>
</Employee>
</Employee_Info>
```

Now this is the code I'm using to display the data:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                Response.Write("<" + reader.Name + ">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                Response.Write(reader.Value + "<br />");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                Response.Write("</" + reader.Name + ">");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now my output is coming out like this:

```
Blah 
001 
ISDC 
Bleh 
002 
COE 
Bah 
003 
Roll_Out
```

How will I display the tags along with the values? That is I want my output in the following format:

```
Name: Blah
ID: 001
Dept: COE
```

And what if I add an extra element in the XML file only at one place like an extra email tag in the 3 employee's info? How will I read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml")");

XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Employee");

foreach (XmlNode emp in nodeList)
{
    foreach (XmlNode child in emp.ChildNodes)
    {
        Response.Write(child.LocalName);
        Response.Write(":");
        Response.Write(child.InnerText);
        Response.Write("\n");
    }

}
```

Hope that helps. If it does mark it as answer.
-Milind

Comment: it's not writing the innertext values.

Comment: Thank you milind! Marked your answer. And please review the edit! :)

Comment: @Syrion Thanks. Glad that I could help. I Can't find any update to my answer. Can you tell the changes ?

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));

var rows = doc.Descendants("Employee").Select(e => new
{
    Name = e.Element("Name").Value,
    ID = e.Element("ID").Value,
    Dept = e.Element("Dept").Value
});

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("Name: {0} <br />", row.Name));
    Response.Write(String.Format("ID: {0} <br />", row.ID));
    Response.Write(String.Format("Dept: {0} <br />", row.Dept));
}
```

OR Without Hard-Coding:

```
foreach (XElement x in doc.Descendants("Employee").Nodes())
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("{0}: {1} <br />", x.Name, x.Value));
}
```

Comment: Thats hard-coding. You shouldn't do hard-coding. What if the name of the node changes or count of child node changes
-Milind

Comment: Removed hard-coding as well and simplified it to max.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use LINQ to XML for simpler:

```
 var result =  xDoc.Descendants("Employee").Select(x => new
                        {
                            Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
                            Id = x.Element("ID").Value,
                            Dept = x.Element("Dept").Value,
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have done it right. If you view the source of your aspx page you should see the XML tag.

```
<employee_info><employee><name>Blah<br></name><id>001<br></id><dept>ISDC<br></dept></employee><employee><name>Bleh<br></name><id>002<br></id><dept>COE<br></dept></employee><employee><name>Bah<br></name><id>003<br></id><dept>Roll_Out<br></dept></employee></employee_info>
```